# Ionic 4 initial slide loads with delay

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, ionic4, ion-slides

I updated my Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4 and since then my slider first loads slide with index 0 and after some seconds it loads the initial slide. Is there a solution for this problem?

This is my HTML

```
    <ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideDidChange()" #myslides style="height:100%; width:100%;">
        <ion-slide>
            <app-noticed-events style="height:100%; width:100%;"></app-noticed-events>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <app-home style="height:100%; width:100%;"></app-home>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <app-map style="height:100%; width:100%;"></app-map>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
```

This is my TS-Code

`slideOpts = {initialSlide:1, zoom: false}`

Could lazyloading be the problem?

Comment: could you add your code ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed setting it like this ?

.html

```
 <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

.ts

```
 slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 2
  };
```

all the options are here http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Comment: This is my HTML
`<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide>
        <app-noticed-events></app-noticed-events>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <app-home></app-home>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <app-map></app-map>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>`

This is my TS-Code
`slideOpts = {initialSlide:1, zoom: false}`

But still get a delay